# Airflow - External task sensor running on different hour

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to create an external sensor under the next configuration

- `DAG-A` Running at `00:00:00`
- `DAG-B` Running at `04:00:00`
- `DAG-B.task` checking the status of a `DAG-A.task`.

The issue is, when the external task sensor from the `DAG-B` pokes the `DAG-A.task` is using the `04:00:00` hour like this:

```
INFO - Poking for DAG-A.task on 2020-06-02T04:00:00+00:00
```

instead:

```
INFO - Poking for DAG-A.task on 2020-06-02T00:00:00+00:00
```

And the task is not found.

Any ideas of parameters to configure to poke at `00:00:00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, just needed to add a `execution_delta` on the external task sensor configuration as next:

```
execution_delta=timedelta(hours=4)
```